# Changing CSS/DOM of default popup page from background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

How can I modify popup page DOM from any listener from background script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two approaches.

1) [Send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the popup script with instruction on how to update the view.

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({updatePopup: true, update: "this", data: "that"});

// popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.updatePopup) {
    switch(message.update) {
      /* ... */
      case "this":
        document.getElementById("this").value = message.data;
        /* ... */
        break;
      /* ... */
    }
  }
});
```

Has an added benefit of not caring whether the popup is actually opened: the message will be sent out, and worst case no-one will act on it.

2) [Obtain direct access](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) to the window object.

```
// background.js

// A rare case of a synchronous API..
var windows = chrome.extension.getViews({type : "popup"});
if(windows) { // If popup is actually open
  var popup = windows[0]; // This is the window object for the popup page
  popup.document.getElementById("this").value = "that";
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful but I could not modify DOM/CSS by your given script when the popup is hidden.

Comment: Indeed you cannot. That's why background.js should never assume it's open.